# What is the best way to check if a file contains a key before adding a new line?

Tags: c#, csv, streamreader, streamwriter

I have a CSV file containing the following columns -

Key,Value

First,Line

Second,Line

Third,Line

I want to add a new Key-Value to this file given the key is not already present in the file using C#? What would be the best way to do this? Would I have to traverse line by line and check for the Keys or is there any other better way?

I am not using the CSVHelper package or any other CSV writer.

Comment: "Would I have to traverse line by line and check for the Keys?" Yes.

Comment: My file can eventually grow large. Wouldn't it be an expensive process?

Comment: How big is this file?

Comment: @Steve For now, very few lines. And it probably won't grow beyond a few hundred lines.

Comment: It sounds like you're using a CSV file as a poor substitute for a database. Databases are meant for this kind of thing. They can index columns for very fast lookups.

Comment: If we are speaking of few hundred lines at maximum I would load everything in memory inside a dictionary, Then write everything back when you finish

Comment: @Steve that sounds reasonable to do.

Comment: @Steve That's still reading every line though.

Comment: @itsme86 Inevitable, but just one time, not for each lookup

Comment: @itsme86 that does make sense. I am exploring options and using database is one of them. For maintenance purpose, I would agree, database is better option.

Comment: The reason for downvote?

Comment: If you must use a text file, you may get better search performance by saving the keys in a sorted list and saving the number of keys per starting letter, then you can jump nearer to the line you are looking for instance.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
string path = @"PathToFile.csv";
string Content = string.Empty;

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path))
{
    Content = reader.ReadToEnd();
    reader.Close();
}

if (!Content.Contains("YourKey"))
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path))
    {
        sw.WriteLine(Content + "\nYourkey,YourValue");
        sw.Close();
    }
}
```

Read the file and write all text to a string variable, check the variable if the key exists, if it doesn't then write content back to the file along with your new key. as the file grows it will take longer and longer to search the whole file but it'll work well for a couple thousand lines.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I think this wouldn't work because the return value will be true for Key present even if it is present as a string in some other column value. I need to verify the Key column only.